# Letting user change default orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-preferences, android-orientation

I would like to allow the user to change the option of allowing Android to be displayed in portrait or landscape. What I do is allow the user to set a preference and then force it on the program.

At this point, I'm using code like so inside `onCreate`:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (prefs.getBoolean("landscapeModeEnabled", false)) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
else { 
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

The problem now is that **it creates the Activity twice** if the screen is not in the 'forced' orientation. That is, a phone in default (portrait) orientation will load the screen twice if the user wants a landscape orientation.

I know I can set this using XML, but that would not allow the user to change the preference of the orientation.

I'm using a `SherlockFragmentActivity` from *Action Bar Sherlock*, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 Activities like this:

> mActivityLand
>
> mActivityPort

with different orientation in the `Manifest`.

Check the preference in previous Activity and launch respective `Activity`. Probably not the best solution :(

Comment: It sounds like it would work, but I'd rather go with something that doesn't require double as many activities :)

Comment: Eww. You want this property for all Activities? If your Activities Orientation is not fixed then user can use your application as he likes it(land/port). You don't even need to give him a preference option. If you can take care of the layouts for different orientation.